# Error de petición ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Saludos amigos programadores tengo una pequeña base de datos donde consulto números telefónicos y la información se despliega al instante gracias a ajax. He migrado este programa con anterioridad y no he tenido ninguna clase de problemas y ahora cuando lo migro a otros equipos me muestra este mensaje.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo un fragmento del código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var consulta;
        //hacemos focus al campo de búsqueda
        $("#busqueda").focus();
                                                                                                     
        //comprobamos si se pulsa una tecla
        $("#busqueda").keyup(function(e){
                                      
              //obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo de búsqueda
              consulta = $("#busqueda").val();
              //hace la búsqueda                                                                                  
              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "buscar.php",
                    data: "b="+consulta,
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                    //imagen de carga
                    $("#resultado").html("<p align='center'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /></p>");
                    },
                    error: function(){
                    alert("error petición ajax");
                    },
                    success: function(data){                                                    
                    $("#resultado").empty();
                    $("#resultado").append(data);                                                             
                    }
              });                                                                         
        });                                                     
});
```

```html
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script>

 <center>
    <div id="patch"><br>
      
      <table cellspacing="0">
        <form  method="post" autocomplete="off" class="para_guardar" onSubmit="return limpiar()" name="formulario" id="formulario" >
          <tr><td><input name="nombre" type="text" required class="nc" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre del contacto"/></td>
            <td><input name="tel" type="text" required class="nc" id="tel" placeholder="Número de telefono"/></td><td><input name="Enviar" type="submit" value="Guardar" />
          </td></tr>
        </form>
      </table>
      
      <div id="result"  ></div><!--Este div muestra se muestra al guardarse un dato-->
      <br>
      <br>
      
      
      <input type="text" id="busqueda" class="busqueda" name="busqueda"  placeholder="Introduzca el nombre o número de telefono"  size="50" />
      <br>
      <br>
    <div id="resultado" ></div> <!--Este div muestra la busqueda en vivo-->
    
    
  </center>
```

Este otro código es de donde sustraigo la información:

```html
<?php

$buscar = $_POST['b'];

if(!empty($buscar)) {   buscar($buscar); }

function buscar($b) {   $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root', 'master3.1416');   mysql_select_db('tel', $con);

  

        
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tel WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$b."%' OR tel LIKE '%".$b."%' order by id desc LIMIT 30 " ,$con);
        
    

  $contar = @mysql_num_rows($sql);

  if($contar == 0){
    echo "No se han encontrado resultados para '<b>".$b."</b>'.";   }else{

    echo "<center>";

    echo"<form  autocomplete='off' class='llamar' onsubmit='return false'  > \n";

    echo"<table cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' > \n";
    echo "<th></th><th>Nombre</th><th>Teléfono</th><th></th>\n";

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

     $id = $row['id'];
     $nombre = $row['nombre'];
     $tel = $row['tel'];

     echo"<tr> \n";

     echo"<td  width='0' > <input type='text'  size='0' name='id[]' value='$id' hidden /> </td> \n";

     echo"<td  width='200' > <input type='text' size='90' class='nnnc' name='nombre[]' value='$nombre' required /> </td> \n";

     echo"<td width='20' > <input type='text' size='20' class='nnnc' name='tel[]' value='$tel' required /> </td> \n";

     echo"</tr> \n";


   }

   echo"</table> \n";

   echo"<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Editar' />";

   echo"</form>";

   echo"</center>";


 } }

?>
```

El sistema está creado en php wamp, soy algo novato en programación agradezco la explicación detallada del problema.

Comment: Saludos. Modifica `error: function(){ alert("error petición ajax"); }` a `error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ /* Usa console.log(jqXHR); y así por cada variable */; }`; así obtendrás mas a detalle parte del error. Lo anterior desde luego saldrá en la consola y desde allí mira los detalles que te aporta.

Comment: Tienes el código mal organizado. En el formulario tienes esto: `onSubmit="return limpiar()`, pero la petición Ajax no se hace desde una función `limpiar()`, la tienes dentro del document.ready, por lo que se está lanzando al cargar el DOM. Para más simplicidad yo quitaría el `onSubmit`, pondría un botón al formulario y lanzaría Ajax desde un bloque de escucha de los clicks de ese botón. Otra cosa que se ve rara es que en el código PHP crees de nuevo un formulario ¿? El archivo PHP que recibe la petición Ajax debe ser como una pasarela entre cliente/servidor. Es fundamental tenelo claro.

Comment: @A.Cedano, no creo que ese sea el origen del problema, porque el código lanzado al cargar el DOM es para _autocompletar_ y es independiente del formulario.

Comment: OK @Triby, admito tu corrección en ese punto, pues no vi que la llamada Ajax estaba dentro de este bloque: `$("#busqueda").keyup(function(e){`, pero mantengo lo dicho al final de mi comentario: no tiene sentido recrear el formulario desde el archivo php que se invoca en la petición Ajax, lo propio sería actualizar los elementos del mismo con la respuesta venida desde el servidor. Es importante que OP entienda que el archivo php que se invoca desde Ajax debe ser una pasarela para recibir/devolver datos y usar esos datos (en el `success` de Ajax) para modificar los elementos, cosa que no hace.

Comment: @A.Cedano, estoy totalmente de acuerdo en el último punto, todo el código puede mejorarse, independientemente de lo que se haga con cada formulario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radica en la versión del appserv 9 no permite la ejecución de mysql_query solo mysqli

Comment: No es en si que la versión de tu server sea el problema, es que esto `mysql_query` dejo de estar en el core de PHP desde hace varios años y entonces si usas un AppServe moderno reciente es lógico que no esté incluido, pero por que PHP ya no lo trae